# Angular start and end symbol input name cant use [[ ]]

Tags: angularjs

Im using [[ as start symbol and ]] as end symbol. But now im running on the issue that name="example[[[$index]]]" is showing up an error. Does anyone have a clue how to solve this issue?

Comment: what you want is example[some-name] but angular searches for expression [somename] because the first two parenthethis trigger the compilation. Dont use [[]], instead use something like <% %> or something else.

Comment: Yeah i know how the compilation works, but i dont have an idea how to solve this properly without changing the end and start symbols

Comment: try name="example&#91;[[$index]]&#93;"